# How to add a Java Properties file to my Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I was using Unix before to compile and edit my Java. In that I have used property files right inside my current working directory where the class file exists. Now i have switched to Eclipse IDE. I dont know how to add the same properties file here in Eclipse. Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work ok as it is in Unix, if you have properties file in current working directory. Another option would be adding your properties file to the classpath and getting the inputstream using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxxxx.properties");`
More [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/10/loading-java-properties-files.html)

Answer (score 32):

1. Create Folder “resources” under Java Resources folder if your project doesn’t have it.

   2. create config.properties file with below value.

[image]

/Java Resources/resources/config.properties

for loading properties.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

      input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");


    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

In the package explorer, right-click on the package and select New -> File, then enter the filename including the ".properties" suffix.

Comment: This does not work anymore. There is no simple `file` option after selecting `New >`. You are forced to choose either a `.HTML` or `.JSP` file (and appropriate file extensions for naming) and you are blocked from naming it with `.properties`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mowzer: what file types are listed directly depends on what eclipse edition you have and maybe even configuration. Apparently you're using one targeted at web development. But you can still choose "other" to get to the plain file option.

Answer (score 4):

steps:

1. Right click on any package where you want to create your .properties file
   or create a new package as required
2. now select new then select file (if you dont find file then go to location of your package and create it there)
3. now named it as yourfilename.properties

Answer (score 2):

If you have created a Java Project in eclipse by using the 'from existing source' option then it should work as it did before. To be more precise **File > New Java Project**. In the Contents section select '*Create project from existing source*' and then select your existing project folder. The wizard will take care of the rest.

Comment: This does not answer the question in anyway

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the folder within your project in eclipse where you want to create property file
2. New->Other->in the search filter type file and in the consecutive window give the name of the file with .properties extension

Answer (score 1):

To create a property class please select your package where you wants to create your property file.

Right click on the package and select other. 
Now select File and type your file name with (.properties) suffix.
For example: db.properties.
Than click finish.
Now you can write your code inside this property file.

Answer (score -2):

If you are working with core java, create your file(.`properties`) by right clicking your project. If the file is present inside your package or src folder it will throw an file not found error