# The config.properties file is not read in java

Tags: java, config

My folder structure is as follows:

```
>test
    >src
         >org.mypackage
                >myclass
    >resources
         >config.properties
```

The java class is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;    

public myclass {

     private String path = "config.properties";

     public myclass() {
         Properties prop = new Properties();
         InputStream input = null;
         try {
             input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
             prop.load(input)
         }
         catch(Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

But I get `null` as the value for `input` during debug.

In the debug mode I checked the value for `getClass()`, I get the class value, the value is also available for `getClass().getClassLoader()` but for `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)` it is `null`.

I am not sure what the issue could be.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: does `"/config.properties"` work?

Comment: Nope that doesnt work too.

Comment: are you using a specific IDE and project setup, like intellij, eclipse, maven?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse neon

Comment: @nandsito A resource string should never start with a slash when it is passed to ClassLoader.getResource.  That only has meaning for Class.getResource.

Comment: @VGR i've always mistaken this subtle difference, thanks for the tip

Comment: Are you loading your app from an application server? If that is the case try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)` or `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `resources` is not a source folder in your Eclipse project. Try setting `resources` as a source folder:

```
Right click > Build Path > Use as Source Folder
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I hadn't configured it as a source folder. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check this question right here, which should help you in answering your problem: [How to add a Java Properties file to my Java Project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776687/how-to-add-a-java-properties-file-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse)

Moreover, it seems to me that your project isn't 100% Maven compliant. You should have something more like:

```
>src
    >main
        >java
        >resources
    >test
        >java
        >resources
```

Then Eclipse should be less lost when handling and loading your properties.

If you have any questions, feel free message me

Comment: I don’t see any mention of Maven in the question.